# Where is my inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox

I've seen the inbox in some popup before, but I've been clicking around and I am not seeing a mail box management/mail list now. I tried to looking at my account page but had no luck. Where is it? Or is the "inbox" actually the inbox of the mail address associated with my account?

Comment: In the upper left of any stack exchange webpage look for `StackExchange` and click that. A box will pop up, and just below the tagline you'll see three selectors, `hot questions`, `all sites`, and `inbox`.  Click on `inbox`.

Comment: Are you looking for the Stack-Exchange-Super-Collider-Multi-Dropdown in the upper left corner, which does have an inbox for notifications?

Comment: You can also go to your stackexchange user page, and click `inbox` in there.  Yours is *probably* here: http://stackexchange.com/users/77654/dr-xray?tab=inbox though, of course, I can't see it.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Yes, the new design, not bad actually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Click the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™. It is the leftmost item in the grey toolbar at the top of the page.

   [image]
2. Click the 'inbox' tab.

   [image]

Comment: Does not work anymore, can you update the answer please?

Comment: @daltonfury42, see [my answer I just added here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387722/285250) for updated instructions.

Comment: (Note for posterity: the info in this answer is slightly outdated now, as the look and position of the inbox dropdown has changed.)

Answer (score 2):

### How to go to your combined inbox for all Stack Exchange sites

#### The short answer:

Option 1: Go here ([thank you @Makyen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123128/where-is-my-inbox/387722#comment1293044_387722)): https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox

Done!

*Or* Option 2: ([thank you @V2Blast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123128/where-is-my-inbox/387722#comment1293045_387722)), on any *specific* stack exchange site, such as here on the Meta site, or on the main Stack Overflow site, click your inbox in the top-right then go to "Go to full inbox" at the bottom of the inbox dropdown menu.
[image]

#### The long answer:

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com/.
2. Click your profile image in the top-right. That brings me here: https://stackexchange.com/users/3032157/gabriel-staples Your URL will have your user ID and name instead of mine.
3. Click "inbox" in the top-right, under your profile description. You'll only see this for your own profile, and only when logged in, *not* for other peoples' profiles or when not logged in.
   [image]
4. There you have it! That brings me to this URL here: https://stackexchange.com/users/3032157/gabriel-staples?tab=inbox Your URL will have your own user ID and username in it.

Comment: The generic address for the current user's global inbox is `https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox`. You can test that [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox)

Comment: You can also click the inbox icon (the one that looks sort of like an open box/bin) near the right side of the top bar on any Stack Exchange site (it's between your profile link and the trophy icon) to open the inbox dropdown. That'll show your most recent notifications from all sites; you can also click the "Go to full inbox" link at the bottom of that dropdown to navigate to the inbox tab of your network profile as shown in your post.

Comment: You missed one. The inbox icon in the top bar itself is a link. If you right click and open in new tab or middle-click, it'll open the global reputation page in its own tab.