# Where is my jobs inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123128/where-is-my-inbox) has an answer from 2012, and seems to be obsolete now, or I am blind and did not find the dropdown stated there.

I recently got a job offer to my inbox (or maybe it is named differently), but can't find it.

How to find incoming messages?

---

Luckily, I saved a screenshot - this is what an inbox message looks like:

[image]

This doesn't look like anything in the global inbox. Or is it?

Comment: I don't parttake in jobs, and questions specifically about jobs should be posted at MSO rather then MSE, but you can go to your global inbox by opening the hyperlink that is hidden on the button that you get your notifications  on.

Comment: @Rob not even remotely. At least because there is no answer there, but also because the question is unrelated

Comment: @Rob I accepted because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox) link. Not [this one](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the navigation bar:

[image]

I haven't received job offers but [I assume](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349390/4751173) they end up in the global inbox as well. To see older messages, use the 'all items' link, which will take you to [the 'inbox' tab of your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).

I also found an inbox specifically for Jobs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox):

[image]

Comment: I guess it is not called "inbox" then. What you show here are really notifications. Is there somewhere more long-lasting holding actual messages sent to me?

Comment: The jobs inbox is the one! Thanks